# When installing python 3.8, haskell was installed

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, python3

When I run *sudo apt install python 3.8* on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, it has installed haskell packages (libghs) together with python and libghs eats more 2 GB disk space. It's seems that module regex '3.8' needs in libghs.

Is it bug of ubuntu package manager? 
Can I safe uninstall haskell packages?

First 300 lines of installation log:

```
victor@ironUbuntu:~/programs/converters$ sudo apt install python 3.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3.8-venv' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-yi-mode-javascript-dev-0.14.1-3f8dc' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blogliterately-dev-0.8.4.3-804c2' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base-compat-prof-0.9.3-8575a' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-extra-prof-1.5.3-801ec' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.8-dbg' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.8-dev' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3-m3u8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-nettle-prof-0.2.0-e3485' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-file-embed-dev-0.0.10-3484f' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.8-minimal' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'clang-3.8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-curl-prof-1.3.8-45ab8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utf8-light-dev-0.4.2-358ce' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-word8-prof-0.1.3-85f4f' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python-rfc3986' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hsx-jmacro-dev-7.3.8-ab142' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-yi-mode-javascript-prof-0.14.1-3f8dc' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-curl-dev-1.3.8-45ab8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libid3-3.8.3-dev' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-word8-dev-0.1.3-85f4f' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-examples' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-gdbm' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-boundedchan-dev-1.0.3.0-73f82' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-yesod-persistent-dev-1.4.3-63780' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-text-binary-dev-0.2.1.1-03183' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-nettle-dev-0.2.0-e3485' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'asterisk-1fb7f5c06d7a2052e38d021b3d8ca151' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base-compat-dev-0.9.3-8575a' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utf8-light-prof-0.4.2-358ce' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-lib2to3' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hsx-jmacro-prof-7.3.8-ab142' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-file-embed-prof-0.0.10-3484f' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-distutils' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-unix-time-dev-0.3.7-5348a' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'pr3287' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libmm-ocaml-b3880' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libid3-3.8.3' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-minimal' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'idle-python3.8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libmm-ocaml-dev-b3880' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libntfs-3g88' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-test-framework-th-prime-prof-0.0.10-338d6' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python-m3u8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-358-updates' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-unix-time-prof-0.3.7-5348a' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-378-updates' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-text-binary-prof-0.2.1.1-03183' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-tk' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-boundedchan-prof-1.0.3.0-73f82' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-test-framework-th-prime-dev-0.0.10-338d6' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.8-stdlib' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3-rfc3986' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-dbg' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-dev' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python3.8-doc' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'cl-rfc2388' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-entropy-prof-0.3.8-e716f' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blogliterately-prof-0.8.4.3-804c2' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-extra-dev-1.5.3-801ec' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-entropy-dev-0.3.8-e716f' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'python-lldb-3.8' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'vdr-abi-2.3.8-debian' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-358' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-378' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.8-testsuite' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-yesod-persistent-prof-1.4.3-63780' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libid3-3.8.3c2a' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-358' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-378' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libid3-3.8.3c2' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'libid3-3.8.3v5' for regex '3.8'
Note, selecting 'asterisk' instead of 'asterisk-1fb7f5c06d7a2052e38d021b3d8ca151'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base-compat-dev' instead of 'libghc-base-compat-dev-0.9.3-8575a'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base-compat-prof' instead of 'libghc-base-compat-prof-0.9.3-8575a'
Note, selecting 'libghc-text-binary-dev' instead of 'libghc-text-binary-dev-0.2.1.1-03183'
Note, selecting 'libghc-text-binary-prof' instead of 'libghc-text-binary-prof-0.2.1.1-03183'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blogliterately-dev' instead of 'libghc-blogliterately-dev-0.8.4.3-804c2'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blogliterately-prof' instead of 'libghc-blogliterately-prof-0.8.4.3-804c2'
Note, selecting 'libghc-boundedchan-dev' instead of 'libghc-boundedchan-dev-1.0.3.0-73f82'
Note, selecting 'libghc-boundedchan-prof' instead of 'libghc-boundedchan-prof-1.0.3.0-73f82'
Note, selecting 'libghc-entropy-dev' instead of 'libghc-entropy-dev-0.3.8-e716f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-entropy-prof' instead of 'libghc-entropy-prof-0.3.8-e716f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-curl-dev' instead of 'libghc-curl-dev-1.3.8-45ab8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-curl-prof' instead of 'libghc-curl-prof-1.3.8-45ab8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-extra-dev' instead of 'libghc-extra-dev-1.5.3-801ec'
Note, selecting 'libghc-extra-prof' instead of 'libghc-extra-prof-1.5.3-801ec'
Note, selecting 'libghc-unix-time-dev' instead of 'libghc-unix-time-dev-0.3.7-5348a'
Note, selecting 'libghc-unix-time-prof' instead of 'libghc-unix-time-prof-0.3.7-5348a'
Note, selecting 'libghc-file-embed-dev' instead of 'libghc-file-embed-dev-0.0.10-3484f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-file-embed-prof' instead of 'libghc-file-embed-prof-0.0.10-3484f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hsx-jmacro-dev' instead of 'libghc-hsx-jmacro-dev-7.3.8-ab142'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hsx-jmacro-prof' instead of 'libghc-hsx-jmacro-prof-7.3.8-ab142'
Note, selecting 'libghc-nettle-dev' instead of 'libghc-nettle-dev-0.2.0-e3485'
Note, selecting 'libghc-nettle-prof' instead of 'libghc-nettle-prof-0.2.0-e3485'
Note, selecting 'libghc-word8-dev' instead of 'libghc-word8-dev-0.1.3-85f4f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-word8-prof' instead of 'libghc-word8-prof-0.1.3-85f4f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-test-framework-th-prime-dev' instead of 'libghc-test-framework-th-prime-dev-0.0.10-338d6'
Note, selecting 'libghc-test-framework-th-prime-prof' instead of 'libghc-test-framework-th-prime-prof-0.0.10-338d6'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utf8-light-dev' instead of 'libghc-utf8-light-dev-0.4.2-358ce'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utf8-light-prof' instead of 'libghc-utf8-light-prof-0.4.2-358ce'
Note, selecting 'libghc-yesod-persistent-dev' instead of 'libghc-yesod-persistent-dev-1.4.3-63780'
Note, selecting 'libghc-yesod-persistent-prof' instead of 'libghc-yesod-persistent-prof-1.4.3-63780'
Note, selecting 'libghc-yi-mode-javascript-dev' instead of 'libghc-yi-mode-javascript-dev-0.14.1-3f8dc'
Note, selecting 'libghc-yi-mode-javascript-prof' instead of 'libghc-yi-mode-javascript-prof-0.14.1-3f8dc'
Note, selecting 'libmm-ocaml' instead of 'libmm-ocaml-b3880'
Note, selecting 'libmm-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libmm-ocaml-dev-b3880'
Note, selecting 'vdr' instead of 'vdr-abi-2.3.8-debian'
Note, selecting 'python3-distutils' instead of 'python3.8-distutils'
Note, selecting 'python3-gdbm' instead of 'python3.8-gdbm'
Note, selecting 'python3-lib2to3' instead of 'python3.8-lib2to3'
Note, selecting 'python3-tk' instead of 'python3.8-tk'
python is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
libntfs-3g88 is already the newest version (1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.2).
python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04).
python3-distutils set to manually installed.
python3-gdbm is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04).
python3-lib2to3 is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04).
python3-lib2to3 set to manually installed.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  3270-common asterisk-config asterisk-core-sounds-en
  asterisk-core-sounds-en-gsm asterisk-modules asterisk-moh-opsound-gsm
  asterisk-voicemail autotools-dev blt camlp4 fonts-mathjax freetds-common ghc
  ghc-prof gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 icu-devtools ledit libbibutils-dev libbibutils2
  libbsd-dev libcamlp4-ocaml-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libffi-dev
  libfindlib-ocaml libfindlib-ocaml-dev libftdi1-2 libghc-adjunctions-dev
  libghc-adjunctions-prof libghc-aeson-compat-dev libghc-aeson-compat-prof
  libghc-aeson-dev libghc-aeson-prof libghc-ansi-terminal-dev
  libghc-ansi-terminal-prof libghc-ansi-wl-pprint-dev
  libghc-ansi-wl-pprint-prof libghc-appar-dev libghc-appar-prof
  libghc-asn1-encoding-dev libghc-asn1-encoding-prof libghc-asn1-parse-dev
  libghc-asn1-parse-prof libghc-asn1-types-dev libghc-asn1-types-prof
  libghc-async-dev libghc-async-prof libghc-attoparsec-dev
  libghc-attoparsec-iso8601-dev libghc-attoparsec-iso8601-prof
  libghc-attoparsec-prof libghc-auto-update-dev libghc-auto-update-prof
  libghc-base-orphans-dev libghc-base-orphans-prof
  libghc-base64-bytestring-dev libghc-base64-bytestring-prof
  libghc-basement-dev libghc-basement-prof libghc-bifunctors-dev
  libghc-bifunctors-prof libghc-blaze-builder-dev libghc-blaze-builder-prof
  libghc-blaze-html-dev libghc-blaze-html-prof libghc-blaze-markup-dev
  libghc-blaze-markup-prof libghc-bool-extras-dev libghc-bool-extras-prof
  libghc-byteable-dev libghc-byteable-prof libghc-byteorder-dev
  libghc-byteorder-prof libghc-call-stack-dev libghc-call-stack-prof
  libghc-case-insensitive-dev libghc-case-insensitive-prof libghc-cereal-dev
  libghc-cereal-prof libghc-charsetdetect-ae-dev libghc-charsetdetect-ae-prof
  libghc-cipher-aes-dev libghc-cipher-aes-prof libghc-clientsession-dev
  libghc-clientsession-prof libghc-clock-dev libghc-clock-prof
  libghc-cmark-dev libghc-cmark-prof libghc-cmdargs-dev libghc-cmdargs-prof
  libghc-comonad-dev libghc-comonad-prof libghc-conduit-dev
  libghc-conduit-extra-dev libghc-conduit-extra-prof libghc-conduit-prof
  libghc-connection-dev libghc-connection-prof libghc-contravariant-dev
  libghc-contravariant-prof libghc-cookie-dev libghc-cookie-prof
  libghc-cpphs-dev libghc-cpphs-prof libghc-cprng-aes-dev
  libghc-cprng-aes-prof libghc-crypto-api-dev libghc-crypto-api-prof
  libghc-crypto-cipher-types-dev libghc-crypto-cipher-types-prof
  libghc-crypto-random-dev libghc-crypto-random-prof libghc-cryptonite-dev
  libghc-cryptonite-prof libghc-data-default-class-dev
  libghc-data-default-class-prof libghc-data-default-dev
  libghc-data-default-instances-containers-dev
  libghc-data-default-instances-containers-prof
  libghc-data-default-instances-dlist-dev
  libghc-data-default-instances-dlist-prof
  libghc-data-default-instances-old-locale-dev
  libghc-data-default-instances-old-locale-prof libghc-data-default-prof
  libghc-deepseq-generics-dev libghc-deepseq-generics-prof libghc-digest-dev
  libghc-digest-prof libghc-distributive-dev libghc-distributive-prof
  libghc-dlist-dev libghc-dlist-prof libghc-doctemplates-dev
  libghc-doctemplates-prof libghc-dynamic-state-dev libghc-dynamic-state-prof
  libghc-easy-file-dev libghc-easy-file-prof libghc-exceptions-dev
  libghc-exceptions-prof libghc-extensible-exceptions-dev
  libghc-extensible-exceptions-prof libghc-fast-logger-dev
  libghc-fast-logger-prof libghc-filemanip-dev libghc-filemanip-prof
  libghc-fingertree-dev libghc-fingertree-prof libghc-fmlist-dev
  libghc-fmlist-prof libghc-foundation-dev libghc-foundation-prof
  libghc-free-dev libghc-free-prof libghc-generic-deriving-dev
  libghc-generic-deriving-prof libghc-haddock-library-dev
  libghc-haddock-library-prof libghc-hashable-dev libghc-hashable-prof
  libghc-haxml-dev libghc-haxml-prof libghc-haxr-dev libghc-haxr-prof
  libghc-highlighting-kate-dev libghc-highlighting-kate-prof
  libghc-hostname-dev libghc-hostname-prof libghc-hourglass-dev
  libghc-hourglass-prof libghc-hs-bibutils-dev libghc-hs-bibutils-prof
  libghc-hscolour-dev libghc-hscolour-prof libghc-hslua-dev libghc-hslua-prof
  libghc-hsopenssl-dev libghc-hsopenssl-prof libghc-hsp-dev libghc-hsp-prof
  libghc-http-api-data-dev libghc-http-api-data-prof libghc-http-client-dev
  libghc-http-client-prof libghc-http-client-tls-dev
  libghc-http-client-tls-prof libghc-http-common-dev libghc-http-common-prof
  libghc-http-date-dev libghc-http-date-prof libghc-http-dev libghc-http-prof
  libghc-http-streams-dev libghc-http-streams-prof libghc-http-types-dev
  libghc-http-types-prof libghc-http2-dev libghc-http2-prof
  libghc-hxt-charproperties-dev libghc-hxt-charproperties-prof libghc-hxt-dev
  libghc-hxt-prof libghc-hxt-regex-xmlschema-dev
  libghc-hxt-regex-xmlschema-prof libghc-hxt-unicode-dev
  libghc-hxt-unicode-prof libghc-integer-logarithms-dev
  libghc-integer-logarithms-prof libghc-io-streams-dev libghc-io-streams-prof
  libghc-iproute-dev libghc-iproute-prof libghc-jmacro-dev libghc-jmacro-prof
  libghc-juicypixels-dev libghc-juicypixels-prof libghc-kan-extensions-dev
  libghc-kan-extensions-prof libghc-lens-dev libghc-lens-prof
  libghc-lifted-base-dev libghc-lifted-base-prof libghc-listlike-dev
  libghc-listlike-prof libghc-math-functions-dev libghc-math-functions-prof
  libghc-memory-dev libghc-memory-prof libghc-microlens-dev
  libghc-microlens-ghc-dev libghc-microlens-ghc-prof libghc-microlens-mtl-dev
  libghc-microlens-mtl-prof libghc-microlens-platform-dev
  libghc-microlens-platform-prof libghc-microlens-prof libghc-microlens-th-dev
  libghc-microlens-th-prof libghc-mime-types-dev libghc-mime-types-prof
  libghc-mmorph-dev libghc-mmorph-prof libghc-monad-control-dev
  libghc-monad-control-prof libghc-monad-logger-dev libghc-monad-logger-prof
  libghc-monad-loops-dev libghc-monad-loops-prof libghc-mtl-dev
  libghc-mtl-prof libghc-mwc-random-dev libghc-mwc-random-prof
  libghc-network-dev libghc-network-prof libghc-network-uri-dev
  libghc-network-uri-prof libghc-old-locale-dev libghc-old-locale-prof
  libghc-old-time-dev libghc-old-time-prof libghc-oo-prototypes-dev
  libghc-oo-prototypes-prof libghc-openssl-streams-dev
  libghc-openssl-streams-prof libghc-pandoc-citeproc-data
  libghc-pandoc-citeproc-dev libghc-pandoc-citeproc-prof libghc-pandoc-dev
  libghc-pandoc-prof libghc-pandoc-types-dev libghc-pandoc-types-prof
  libghc-parallel-dev libghc-parallel-prof libghc-parseargs-dev
  libghc-parsec3-dev libghc-parsec3-prof libghc-path-pieces-dev
  libghc-path-pieces-prof libghc-pcre-light-dev libghc-pcre-light-prof
  libghc-pem-dev libghc-pem-prof libghc-persistent-dev libghc-persistent-prof
  libghc-persistent-template-dev libghc-persistent-template-prof
  libghc-pointedlist-dev libghc-pointedlist-prof libghc-polyparse-dev
  libghc-polyparse-prof libghc-prelude-extras-dev libghc-prelude-extras-prof
  libghc-primitive-dev libghc-primitive-prof libghc-process-extras-dev
  libghc-process-extras-prof libghc-profunctors-dev libghc-profunctors-prof
  libghc-psqueues-dev libghc-psqueues-prof libghc-quickcheck2-dev
  libghc-quickcheck2-prof libghc-random-dev libghc-random-prof
  libghc-reflection-dev libghc-reflection-prof libghc-regex-base-dev
  libghc-regex-base-prof libghc-regex-pcre-dev libghc-regex-pcre-prof
  libghc-regex-posix-dev libghc-regex-posix-prof libghc-regex-tdfa-dev
  libghc-regex-tdfa-prof libghc-resource-pool-dev libghc-resource-pool-prof
  libghc-resourcet-dev libghc-resourcet-prof libghc-safe-dev libghc-safe-prof
  libghc-scientific-dev libghc-scientific-prof libghc-securemem-dev
  libghc-securemem-prof libghc-semigroupoids-dev libghc-semigroupoids-prof
  libghc-semigroups-dev libghc-semigroups-prof libghc-setenv-dev
  libghc-setenv-prof libghc-sha-dev libghc-sha-prof libghc-shakespeare-dev
  libghc-shakespeare-prof libghc-silently-dev libghc-silently-prof
  libghc-simple-sendfile-dev libghc-simple-sendfile-prof libghc-skein-dev
  libghc-skein-prof libghc-skylighting-dev libghc-skylighting-prof
  libghc-socks-dev libghc-socks-prof libghc-split-dev libghc-split-prof
  libghc-src-exts-dev libghc-src-exts-prof libghc-src-meta-dev
  libghc-src-meta-prof libghc-statevar-dev libghc-statevar-prof
  libghc-stm-chans-dev libghc-stm-chans-prof libghc-stm-dev libghc-stm-prof
  libghc-streaming-commons-dev libghc-streaming-commons-prof libghc-strict-dev
  libghc-strict-prof libghc-stringsearch-dev libghc-stringsearch-prof
  libghc-syb-dev libghc-syb-prof libghc-tagged-dev libghc-tagged-prof
  libghc-tagsoup-dev libghc-tagsoup-prof libghc-temporary-dev
  libghc-temporary-prof libghc-test-framework-dev libghc-test-framework-prof
  libghc-texmath-dev libghc-texmath-prof libghc-text-dev libghc-text-icu-dev
  libghc-text-icu-prof libghc-text-prof libghc-tf-random-dev
  libghc-tf-random-prof libghc-th-abstraction-dev libghc-th-abstraction-prof
  libghc-th-expand-syns-dev libghc-th-expand-syns-prof libghc-th-lift-dev
  libghc-th-lift-instances-dev libghc-th-lift-instances-prof
  libghc-th-lift-prof libghc-th-orphans-dev libghc-th-orphans-prof
  libghc-th-reify-many-dev libghc-th-reify-many-prof
  libghc-time-locale-compat-dev libghc-time-locale-compat-prof libghc-tls-dev
  libghc-tls-prof libghc-transformers-base-dev libghc-transformers-base-prof
  libghc-transformers-compat-dev libghc-transformers-compat-prof
  libghc-unix-compat-dev libghc-unix-compat-prof
  libghc-unordered-containers-dev libghc-unordered-containers-prof
  libghc-uri-bytestring-dev libghc-uri-bytestring-prof libghc-utf8-string-dev
  libghc-utf8-string-prof libghc-uuid-types-dev libghc-uuid-types-prof
  libghc-vault-dev libghc-vault-prof libghc-vector-dev libghc-vector-prof
  libghc-vector-th-unbox-dev libghc-vector-th-unbox-prof libghc-void-dev
  libghc-void-prof libghc-wai-dev libghc-wai-extra-dev libghc-wai-extra-prof
  libghc-wai-logger-dev libghc-wai-logger-prof libghc-wai-prof libghc-warp-dev
  libghc-warp-prof libghc-wl-pprint-text-dev libghc-wl-pprint-text-prof
  libghc-x509-dev libghc-x509-prof libghc-x509-store-dev
  libghc-x509-store-prof libghc-x509-system-dev libghc-x509-system-prof
  libghc-x509-validation-dev libghc-x509-validation-prof
  libghc-xdg-basedir-dev libghc-xdg-basedir-prof libghc-xml-conduit-dev
  libghc-xml-conduit-prof libghc-xml-dev libghc-xml-prof libghc-xml-types-dev
  libghc-xml-types-prof libghc-yaml-dev libghc-yaml-prof libghc-yesod-core-dev
  libghc-yesod-core-prof libghc-yi-core-dev libghc-yi-core-prof
  libghc-yi-language-dev libghc-yi-language-prof libghc-yi-rope-dev
  libghc-yi-rope-prof libghc-zip-archive-dev libghc-zip-archive-prof
  libghc-zlib-bindings-dev libghc-zlib-bindings-prof libghc-zlib-dev
  libghc-zlib-prof libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl
  libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libicu-dev
  libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libid3-tools libiksemel3
  libjs-mathjax liblirc0 libltdl-dev liblua5.1-0 liblua5.1-0-dev
  libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libluajit-5.1-dev libncurses5-dev
  libodbc1 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev
  libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpj2 libpjlib-util2 libpjmedia2 libpjnath2
  libpjsip-simple2 libpjsip-ua2 libpjsip2 libportaudio2 libpq5 libradcli4
  libreadline-dev libresample1 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox3
  libspandsp2 libsqlite0 libsrtp2-1 libsybdb5 libtinfo-dev libtool libtool-bin
  liburiparser1 libusb-0.1-4 libvo-amrwbenc0 libyaml-dev lirc nettle-dev
  ocaml-base-nox ocaml-compiler-libs ocaml-findlib ocaml-interp ocaml-nox
  pkg-config python-iso8601 python3-iso8601 sox tk8.6-blt2.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command installed haskell because it is a badly formed command. As the installation log says:

```
Note, selecting ... for regex '3.8'
```

because `sudo apt install python 3.8` splits python3.8 into two separate arguments, `python` and `3.8` which is a typo error that caused 2GB of unnecessary packages to be installed. All the packages that are listed after `The following additional packages will be installed:` didn't need to be installed and can be safely removed with `sudo apt remove` followed by the whole list of packages that didn't need to be installed.

The commands to install Python 3.8 in Ubuntu 18.04 are:

```
sudo update
sudo apt install python3.8
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that using regex instead of exact match for package install is counterintuitive and dangerous. One typo and...surprise!